# How to set correct html property "lang" for multilingual site on Angular with Transloco?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, multilingual, lang, transloco

I made multilingual web site (3 languages) on Angular using Transloco. Means, I don't have different page versions or sub domain for every language, I just have all text content in Transloco json files. And it's only one file index.html, where I can set html property "lang". How can I do it for some different languages?

And another one: I translate tags title and description and I set it with different content for every page in SPA. Is it enough or should I do something else?
Sorry for maybe stupid question, but it's my first "SEO".

Now it looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
```

So it's not ok.
For changing title, for example, I use the updateTitle method and I'm just changing current title value with Transloco.

I have the information about current language in LocalStorage, means I can get "en","it" or "es" via localStorage.getItem("lang"), but how can I place it in `<html lang="">`?